# Call another function and make it return directly to this function's caller

Tags: c

I often find myself writing one-line shell script wrappers like this (simple example):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/ls -la "$@"
```

Here, `exec` makes the shell execute the specified program without `fork()`ing, so you don't get the overhead of the shell process *and* `ls` running (and the return code of `ls` is returned directly to the program that launched this script).

Then sometimes I write C functions like this (heavily simplified example):

```c
int b(int val1, int val2);

int a(int val) {
    return b(val, 0);
}
```

Sometimes `a()` does a little more heavy lifting than this, but it then calls `b()` with some new set of arguments and **returns its result directly, without modification**. I'm struck by the conceptual similarity to how the `exec` wrapper script I showed above behaves (though they're completely different under the hood, of course). However, my knowledge of assembly/machine code is limited, so I don't know how I would accomplish something similar to `exec`.

1. To state the question generally: Is it possible to make a function `a()` somehow "replace" itself with a call to another function `b()`, such that `b()` will return its result **directly to `a()`'s caller** without going through `a()` itself? (Is this architecture-dependent?)
2. Will this yield any sort of memory usage/performance improvement?
3. Can this be done if `b()` is a function in a dynamically linked library (`execvp()`, as an example)?
4. *Are modern compilers already doing this?*

Notes:

- Assume `a()` and `b()` above are **not** automatically inlined by the compiler, since inlining either `a()` or `b()` would defeat the purpose.
- The arguments passed to `b()` may be the same as the original arguments to the `a()` (i.e. it just does some additional setup) or some of them may be different/reordered.

Comment: Compilers are doing this. The most glaring manifestation is the tail recursion unrolling. (I hope I understood the question correctly)

Comment: With x86 [and arm, mips], the first few args are passed in registers. Loosely, in `a`, the first arg is passed as the first arg (e.g. `r0`)--so no change. `a` will put 0 in the second arg [register] to `b`. So, it's just two instructions: `mov 0,r1` and `jmp b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, compilers already do this. Consider the following code:

```c
extern int b(int val1, int val2);

int a(int val) {
    return b(val, 0);
}
```

Compile with `cc test.c -O3 -c -o test.o`, and dump with `otool -tv test.o` (I'm on a Mac):

```
_a:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    xorl    %esi, %esi
0000000000000006    popq    %rbp
0000000000000007    jmp _b
```

Usually, to call a function, you use the x86 instruction `call`, which pushes a return address on the stack (creating a new stack frame). But, here, the compiler uses `jmp`, which does not establish a new stack frame; this is the closest equivalent to "exec" in assembly.